# How to batch CsvDataset correctly in Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm using `tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset` to create a dataset from a .csv file. I'm also using `tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures` as an input layer of my model.

I'm struggling to create a `DenseFeatures` layer properly so that it is compatible with my dataset in the case when `batch_size` parameter of `make_csv_dataset` is not equal to 1 (in case if `batch_size=1` my setup works as expected).

I create `DenseFeatures` layer using a list of `tf.feature_column.numeric_column` elements with `shape=(my_batch_size,)`, but it seems like in this case for some reason the input layer expects `[my_batch_size,my_batch_size]` shape instead of `[my_batch_size,1]`.

With `my_batch_size=19` I'm getting the following error when trying to fit the model:

```
ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 19 elements to shape [19,19] (361 elements) for 'MyModel/Input/MyColumn1/Reshape' (op: 'Reshape') with input shapes: [19,1], [2] and with input
tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [19,19].
```

If I don't specify `shape` when creating `numeric_column` it doesn't work either. I'm getting the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  The second input must be a scalar, but it has shape [19]
```

which assumes that `numeric_column` expects a scalar but recieves the whole batch in one `Tensor`.

How do I create an input layer of `DenseFeatures` so that it accepts the dataset produced by `make_csv_dataset(batch_size=my_batch_size)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `tf.feature_column.numeric_column` documentation:

> **`shape`**: An iterable of integers specifies the shape of the **`Tensor`**. An integer can be given which means a single dimension **`Tensor`** with given width. The **`Tensor`** representing the column will have the shape of [batch_size] + **`shape`**.

This means that you must not pass the batch size to the `shape` argument: `shape=()`.

Currently, with a batch size of 1, you get `shape=(1,)` that TF can handle thanks to broadcasting or something like that (dimensions of size 1 are easily added by TF if necessary), that's why it works.

Hope this can help. Provide more code if you want more help.

Comment: If I don't specify `shape` it doesn't work either.

I'm getting the following error: `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  The second input must be a scalar, but it has shape [19]` which assumes that `numeric_column` is expecting a scalar but receiving the whole batch as one Tensor. So, I'm still not sure how to use `numeric_column` together with the batched `CsvDataset`.

Comment: @VolodymyrFrolov You have to specify the `shape` argument, but giving an empty list or tuple: `shape=()` which is not the same that not specifying it, falling back on the default value of `(1,)`. Else, you have to resize manually your samples in a way that your batch has shape `[19, 1]` and not just `[19]`. Moreover, please provide a minimal example to allow us to better help you.

Comment: Specifying `shape=()` helped, additional resizing `[19]` to `[19,1]` was not needed. I also had a problem with my custom loss function where it was casting input tensor to a scalar. I found the problem by putting together a minimal example. Thanks for your help

Comment: @VolodymyrFrolov Additional resizing is only required if you want to let the default `shape` value. The matchings between the `shape` argument and your batch shape is as follow: `shape=() <=> batch.shape=[19]` or `shape=(1,) <=> batch.shape=[19,1]`. My advice is to use tensors of size 1 instead of scalars in your models; this will more often match what is expected by TF API (as it is the case here with the default value of the `shape` argument). Happy to help !

Comment: Understood. I agree that using scalars is not a good practice, so I'll rewrite my code to use tensors instead and to be shape-agnostic.